# Pandas indexing behavior after grouping: do I see an "extra row"?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

This might be a very simple question, but I am trying to understand how grouping and indexing work in pandas.

Let's say I have a DataFrame with the following data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={
    'p_id': [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4],
    'rating': [5, 3, 2, 2, 5, 1, 3, 4, 5]
})
```

Now, the index would be assigned automatically, so the DataFrame looks like:

```
      p_id    rating
0     1       5
1     1       3
2     1       2
3     2       2
4     3       5
5     3       1
6     3       3
7     4       4
8     4       5
```

When I try to group it by `p_id`, I get:

```
>> df[['p_id', 'rating']].groupby('p_id').count()
           rating
p_id        
1          3
2          1
3          3
4          2
```

**I noticed that `p_id` now becomes an index for the grouped DataFrame, but the first row looks weird to me -- why does it have `p_id` index in it with empty rating?**

I know how to fix it, kind of, if I do this:

```
>> df[['p_id', 'rating']].groupby('p_id', as_index=False).count()
      p_id    rating
0     1       3
1     2       1
2     3       3
3     4       2
```

Now I don't have this weird first column, but I have both index and `p_id`.

**So my question is, where does this extra row coming from when I don't use `as_index=False` and is there a way to group DataFrame and keep `p_id` as index while not having to deal with this extra row?** If there are any docs I can read on this, that would also be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just an index name...

Demo:

```
In [46]: df
Out[46]:
   p_id  rating
0     1       5
1     1       3
2     1       2
3     2       2
4     3       5
5     3       1
6     3       3
7     4       4
8     4       5

In [47]: df.index.name = 'AAA'
```

pay attention at the index name: `AAA`

```
In [48]: df
Out[48]:
     p_id  rating
AAA
0       1       5
1       1       3
2       1       2
3       2       2
4       3       5
5       3       1
6       3       3
7       4       4
8       4       5
```

You can get rid of it using [rename_axis()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) method:

```
In [42]: df[['p_id', 'rating']].groupby('p_id').count().rename_axis(None)
Out[42]:
   rating
1       3
2       1
3       3
4       2
```

Comment: Thanks for a shortcut with rename_axis. I know how to get rid of, but it feels a bit awkward that it's there in a first place. I am just curious about why it happens in the first place.

Comment: Because it's an index name. Try the following with your source sample DF: `df.index.name = 'AAA'; print(df)`

Comment: Oh ok, got it, so it's not an empty row then. Thanks for clarification and apologies for a dumb question :)

Comment: Not a dumb question. You are trying to understand it, good for you for doing so.

Comment: @Bruhnswik, yes, bernie is right. I think there is no such thing like dumb questions. Often we see questions which aren't clear because of  missing information, examples, etc., but in your case it was very clear - what was your question / problem and what do you want to achieve

Comment: Nice to see you back

Answer (score 1):

**There is no "extra row"**, it's simply how pandas visually renders a GroupBy object, i.e. how `pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy.__str__` method renders a grouped dataframe object: `rating` is the column, **but now `p_id` has now gone from being a column to being the (row) index.**

Another reason they stagger them (i.e. the row with the column names, and the row with the index/multi-index name) is because the index can be a MultiIndex (if you grouped-by multiple columns).